# JAXB - generating classes from XSD - converting enums to custom toString() other than enum name

Tags: java, enums, xsd, jaxb, tostring

Using JAXB, we generate our Java beans directly. In the XSD, we have an enumerated type(say):

```
<xs:simpleType name="ColorType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:enumeration value="Red"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="Blue"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="Green"/>
</xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType>
```

In the database, we may have flags like R, B and G for Red, Black and green. In a way, we have flags as just 1 letter word. I want to enum, such that ... **ColorType.Red.toString()** is *equal* to **R** ... or something similar, such that I can link R to it. Right now I am manually checking for enumtype using some conditional statement, and then while inserting or any database operation I am converting back to string.

Some stupid solution which came to my mind to solve this (Stupid as, these solutions are not good)
I think one solution to solve this using

```
<xs:enumeration value="R">
```

but this doesn't tells me what is R.

Second solution can be making ColorType as string, but this means my ColorType can be even Z, which is not any color in database, in a way I mean it will be unrestrictive. :( ...

Any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a XJB-Binding for that, like this

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="MySchema.xsd" node="xs:simpleType[@name='ColorType']">
    <jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Red" name="R" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Green" name="G" />
        <jxb:typesafeEnumMember value="Blue" name="B" />
    </jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This will generate an Enum containing the desired mapping. You can access the value by calling the generated `value()`-Method of the Enum. (Don't forget to put the correct schema location into the binding unless your XSD is called MySchema.xsd)

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.1/jaxws/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingEnum.html

Appears I misread your problem. The only solution I can see is to override the generated class toString method. Replace it with one that only returns the first letter of your Enum value. That way RED will return R.

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. But the link you have shared, tells in the beginning that if enum type value is not 'xsd:string', than it tells about defining mapping for int or other type. But my problem, string mapping for string of 1 char :(

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I am using intermediate solution. For now I am just using another ENUM, with a static method in it to return the XSD type enum.

So now have 1 xsd enum (generated) :

```
<xs:simpleType name="ColorType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:enumeration value="Red"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="Blue"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="Green"/>
</xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType>
```

Another enum is manually implemented one in java :

```
enum ColorCode{ 
   Red("R"), Green("G"), Blue("B") ;
   private String clrCode;
   ColorCode(String s){
      clrCode = s;
   }

   public String toString(){
      return clrCode;
   }

   public static ColorCode getColorCode(ColorType clrTypeEnum){
       switch(clrTypeEnum){
          case RED: return Red; break;
          case BLUE: return Blue; break;
          case GREEN: return Green; break;
       }
   }
}
```

Now we can get color code to insert in database, rather than writing if - else code again and again to get color code. Using another enum as mapper, provide restriction than free typed types like string.

At least this is the solution I have worked out for now, don't know if better solution exists, please let me know if something better exists, it will be of great help :)